# RestTemplate Accessing elements in Response

Tags: java, spring-boot, httpresponse, spotify, resttemplate

I have recently started learning Java and Spring boot and wanted to consume the Spotify api to get information on artists.

I've used the following and I get a response

```
String accessToken = getToken(); // method made to generate token
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<Object> retrieveArtistInfo = restTemplate.exchange("https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists"+"?ids="+Arrays.toString(ids).replace("[", "").replace("]", ""), HttpMethod.GET, request, Object.class);



Response: 

{
"artists": [
{
"headers": {
"Content-Type": [
"application/json; charset=utf-8"
],
"Cache-Control": [
"public, max-age=72437"
],
"X-Robots-Tag": [
"noindex, nofollow"
],
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": [
"*"
],
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": [
"Accept, App-Platform, Authorization, Content-Type, Origin, Retry-After, Spotify-App-Version, X-Cloud-Trace-Context"
],
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods": [
"GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, PATCH"
],
"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": [
"true"
],
"Access-Control-Max-Age": [
"604800"
],
"content-length": [
"916"
],
"Date": [
"Mon, 13 Apr 2020 07:42:09 GMT"
],
"Via": [
"1.1 google"
],
"Alt-Svc": [
"clear"
]
},
"body": {
"artists": [
{
"external_urls": {
"spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/4q3ewBCX7sLwd24euuV69X"
},
"followers": {
"href": null,
"total": 20399255
},
"genres": [
"latin",
"reggaeton",
"trap latino"
],
"href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4q3ewBCX7sLwd24euuV69X",
"id": "4q3ewBCX7sLwd24euuV69X",
"images": [
{
"height": 640,
"url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/23009960c33ef08d5973440cca17985a6c70a515",
"width": 640
},
{
"height": 320,
"url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/8ff3e392402169f239bce72b3d80c701b75150b8",
"width": 320
},
{
"height": 160,
"url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/624dd15f5bdcc1bae5fa47739601f3e0be62ebda",
"width": 160
}
],
"name": "Bad Bunny",
"popularity": 100,
"type": "artist",
"uri": "spotify:artist:4q3ewBCX7sLwd24euuV69X"
}
]
},
"statusCode": "OK",
"statusCodeValue": 200
}
]
}
```

I can see the response body by passing retrieveArtistInfo.getBody() but I would want to get things like genres, external urls out of the object i stored it in and make my own response but I don't know to go about in accessing those elements. Would anyone have some tips on how to be able to get that ?

Answer (score 0):

The data format you're looking at there is called JSON. To get access to that data you'll need to parse it. There are lots of tools in the Spring world to parse and interact with that data format. A few links below

A JSON intro:

- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iiADhChRriM

In the Spring world there are a lot of tools to automatically turn that data into an object that you can use. Or you could just parse it to a map. Some examples (there are others):

- Jackson: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson
- org.json: https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by parsing json object as Joe W stated before, 
To do by using *com.google.gson*

```
   ResponseEntity<String> response= restTemplate.getForEntity($url,String.class);//get response as string   
   JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();                 
   JsonObject jo = (JsonObject)jsonParser.parse(response.getBody()); Convert JSON To POJO ( Java Class), which is mapped with JSON properties returned as body from response which you sent request
```

Then access properties via *getter methods of object(functions prefixed with "get".*
**Eg:**

```
    jo.getAsJsonObject("response").getAsJsonArray("artists")
```

Comment: This is what I tried

ResponseEntity<Artists> retrieveArtist = restTemplate.exchange("https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists"+"?ids="+Arrays.toString(ids).replace("[", "").replace("]", ""), HttpMethod.GET, request, Artists.class);



       
//Made this to see if i would be getting the external_urls from the response
 
 JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
 JsonObject jo = (JsonObject)jsonParser.parse(String.valueOf(retrieveArtist.getBody()));

But now I am getting: 

"class com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive cannot be cast to class com.google.gson.JsonObject

Comment: `restTemplate.exchange("api.spotify.com/v1/…", "").replace("]", ""), HttpMethod.GET, request, Artists.class);` 
try ->
`ResponseEntity<String> responseBody= restTemplate.exchange("api.spotify.com/v1/…", HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
JsonParser(); JsonObject jo = (JsonObject)jsonParser.parse(String.valueOf(responseBody.getBody()));` 

I think your Artists class does not have body, you have to get response as String, then convert it to JSON via jsonParser